# SpringBoot application with multiple application.properties running under Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8, application.properties

I need two application.properties in my Spring Boot App.

I know that using the annotation `@PropertySource` I can specify more than 1 property files.

I tried to use: `@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties","classpath:external.properties"})`

The idea of it is having `application.properties` with the machine independent properties and this file will be included inside the war file.

The other file (`external.properties`), will leave in the machine, and won't be included in the war file. Here I want to leave properties like the database connection and so on.

I've already changed catalina.properties for adding the external.properties location into the classpath, but unfortunately when running on Eclipse it doesn't work (complains about the missing database properties.).

Comment: So, you don't want to add external.properties under src folder? Am I understanding it right? Can you try adding it in Properties -> Java Build Path -> Link Source in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

If the external properties file will be available in a known location on the machine, then have an environment variable, system property, or command-line argument set up with the path to the file. Then, reference the file in you `@PropertySource` annotation using `file:` rather than `classpath:`

Example: `@PropertySource("file:${CONF_DIR}/external.properties")`

References:
[Spring boot docs on external configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

[PropertySource documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

[Blog post regarding PropertySource](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/)